# is there a way to set all cells in a dataframe in the form of a vector as NA?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a dataframe in R, and I am trying to set all cells in the form of a vector, either c(1,2,3) or 1:2 to NA. Is there any easy way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lengths` to count number of elements in each value of column. Set them to `NA` where the length is greater than 1. Here I am considering dataframe name as `df` and column name as `col_name`. Change them according to your data.

```
df$col_name[lengths(df$col_name) > 1] <- NA
```